# Can't find the syntax error in my EJS file

Tags: javascript, ejs

I've been working on an ejs file and have ecnountered the following syntax error-

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in <path to ejs file> while compiling ejs

If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint
Or, if you meant to create an async function, pass `async: true` as an option.
    at new Function (<anonymous>)
```

I've been searching Google and SO to see other people's solutions to the same error but couldnt yet find whats wrong in my code.

This is the EJS file (the header and footer worked beforehand)-

```
<%- include("partials/header.ejs") %>

<h1>Please address the following tickets according to their urgency</h1>

<div class="box">
  <% openTickets.forEach(fucntion(ticket){ %>
  <div class="item">
    <form action="/resolve" method="post">
      <p><%= ticket.ticketNumber %></p>
      <p><%= ticket.employeeName %></p>
      <p><%= ticket.departmentName %></p>
      <p><%= ticket.urgencyLevel %></p>
      <p><%= ticket.incidentDescp %></p>
      <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Resolve</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <% }); %>
</div>

<%- include("partials/footer.ejs") %>
```

Would highly appericiate any help.

Comment: `fucntion` should probably be `function`

Comment: @derpirscher I can't believe I haven't noticed that earlier. Much thanks!